# Transit visa for Brussels for Jordanian citizens

Tags: transit, bru, jordanian-citizens

I am travelling from UAE to Russia in the coming month.

My flight will halt for about 4 hr at Brussels, there I will take another flight to Russia. 
  May I know whether I would require transit Visa-on-arrival at Brussels Airport, if for any unexpected reason passengers are asked to disembark the flight?

I am a Jordanian citizen.

Answer (score 2):

**Jordanian citizens do not need an airside transit visa in Belgium**, so as long as you are staying airside (not going through Immigration) and connecting to another flight outside Schengen.  See [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) for more detail and sources.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "any unexpected reason"?  If something extraordinary happens (fire at the airport etc) some sort of visa will be arranged.  If you're refused boarding on your flight to Russia, though, you will be sent back to Jordan.